# Creating heat map of NYC

Tags: r, matlab, heatmap

I have gathered some data on Excel (NYC Subway stations daily load). First column has station name, second column has occupancy and third and fourth columns have longtitude and latitude in the form below.

[image]

How can I convert this into a heatmap of NYC? I know coding in R or Matlab, but I am open to any other convenient methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start, with only five observation a heat map might not be the best way to visualize the given data. Making each observation a point and then color-code by occupancy may be a better way to tackle the given problem. In general, anytime I have longitude and latitude data I use the GGMap library from R and the Google Maps API to plot the data. The code to makes a heat map (if that's what you really want) in R can be found below but note that you must have a Google Maps API key(Free for students!!).

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggmap)
library(devtools)


register_google("YOUR_API_KEY")

nyc_map <- get_map(location = c(lon = -74.00, lat = 40.71), maptype = "terrain", zoom = 13)

 ggmap(nyc_map) + 
    geom_density2d(data = data, aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude, fill = Occupancy), size = 0.3) + 
    stat_density2d(data = data, aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude, fill = ..level.., alpha = ..level..), size = 0.01, bins = 16, geom = "polygon") + 
    scale_fill_gradient(low = "green", high = "red") + 
    scale_alpha(range = c(0, 0.3), guide = FALSE)
```

[image]

It is not perfect but this is a quick way to make a heat map and a good place to start. Note that the stations are quite far apart so adding more observations may make the plot better.
I used [ggmap-demo-heat](https://app.dominodatalab.com/u/seanlorenz/ggmap-demo/view/ggmap-demo-heat.R) to get the code to make the heat map. Again I would recommend using single points for each station (geom_point) and then color each by occupancy. `geom_point(data = data, aes(x =  Longitude, y = Latitude, col = occupany))` might be a good place to start.

Comment: Thank you very much! Actually I have 52 points but I had coped and pasted 5 of them here. Maybe it's better to show them with small blobs with different sizes and colors depending on occupancy. I'll work on the parameters. This saved my bacon!

Answer (score 1):

Qgis is an opensource tool. In it, you can create a layer from a .csv file and then, in the layer properties ==> Style choose heatmap and modify other variables. Once done with this step, under raster==> heatmap, modify other parameters and you are done.